# .htaccess: Redirect domain to https not working if also changing the root path

Tags: php, .htaccess, server

I have the following domains:

```
example1.com
example2.com
example3.com
```

The domains point to `/public_html/`. There are three things I want to do in `/public_html/.htaccess`:

1. Redirect (with all parameters and paths) the domains `example2.com` and `example3.com` to the domain `example1.com`.
2. `example1.com` itself should get shown (if not, then redirect) always with `https` and `www`, means: `https://www.example1.com`
3. The custom root path for the domains is `/public_html/`. I want to change this to `/public_html/example_path/`.

I have the following in `/public_html/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example2.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example2.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example1.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example3.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example3.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example1.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example1.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example1.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example1.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example1.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !example_path/
RewriteRule (.*) /example_path/$1 [L]
```

This is nearly working as expected. But when opening `http://www.example1.com` there is no redirection to `https://www.example1.com`. This is only working when removing the last four code lines, that should change the root path.

For all other domains it's working.

Why isn't it woking for `http://www.example1.com`? And why is it only working when not changing the root path?

Comment: @kerbholz Sorry, this was a mistake. I changed it. I meant `example1.com`.

Comment: Why don't you combine conditions with same rule result? First three rules can be unified.

Comment: @user3153340 You mean, I need the line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example1.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]` only once? Or, what do you mean?

Comment: I've meant exactly what JarekBaran wrote down here. Instead of checking one by one the entered domains, you just need to check if it's different than the one you want as the result. The first three rules are combined as one.

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule to yours at the top of the .htaccess file

```
# http <> https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or check these rewrites instead of your rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example1.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example1\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example1.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !example_path/
    RewriteRule (.*) /example_path/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

For specific domains (www/non-www  example-other.co, www/non-www example3.com, www/non-www example2.com, example1.com)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # http www/non-www example-other.com/any to https://www.example-other.com/any
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example-other\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example-other.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # https non-www example-other.com/any to https://www.example-other.com/any
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example-other\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example-other.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # http www/non-www example1.com/any to https://www.example1.com/any
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example1\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example1.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # http/https www/non-www example2.com/any to https://www.example1.com/any
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example2\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example1.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # http/https www/non-www example3.com/any to https://www.example1.com/any
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example3\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example1.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # https non-www example1.com/any to https://www.example1.com/any
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example1\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example1.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Rewrite /any to /example_path/any 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !example_path/
    RewriteRule (.*) /example_path/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: The first one is working, thanks. But, why? What is it doing?

Comment: It's redirect all http:// requests to https:// ex. `http://www.example1.com` to `https://www.example1.com/`

Comment: There are some other domains that I don't want to redirect to `http://www.example1.com`. How can I exclude them?

Comment: I have added an example for individual domains.

Comment: I'm speaking of e.g. `example-other.com`. This should also get redirected to `https://www` but not to the domain `example1.com`. How can I do that?